# C# File handling - creating a file and opening

Tags: c#, file, file-io, directory, streamwriter

This is what I did to create and write on my file:

```
    Create_Directory = @"" + path;
    Create_Name = file_name;

    private void Create_File(string Create_Directory, string Create_Name )
    {
        string pathString = Create_Directory;
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString)) { System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString); }

        string fileName = Create_Name + ".txt";
        pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathString, fileName);
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathString)) { System.IO.File.Create(pathString); }

        ///ERROR BE HERE:
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(pathString);
        file.WriteLine(Some_Method(MP.Mwidth, MP.Mheight, MP.Mtype, "" )); 
        file.Close();
    }
```

The problem here, which I have battled the entire day, is writing the file after I create it. So, my program creates a file just fine, then gives out an error before writing:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

"Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'D:\Projects\Project 15\Project 15\world\world maps\A.txt' because it is being used by another process."

Funny thing though, when I run the program again and try to create an already existing file, as you can see, it skips file creating, goes to writing and works fine, and I would really want my program to create the file and write without having to rerun it... What am I not seeing here?? :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that [File.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) returns an opened `Stream`, and you're never closing it.  The file is "in use" (by you) at the point in time when you create your `StreamWriter`.

That being said, you don't need to "create" the file.  `StreamWriter` will automatically do it for you.  Just remove this line:

```
   if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathString)) { System.IO.File.Create(pathString); }
```

And everything should work as written.

Note that I would rewrite this slightly, however, to make it safer:

```
private void Create_File(string directory, string filenameWithoutExtension )
{
    // You can just call it - it won't matter if it exists
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

    string fileName = filenameWithoutExtension + ".txt";
    string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, fileName);

    using(System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(pathString))
    {
        file.WriteLine(Some_Method(MP.Mwidth, MP.Mheight, MP.Mtype, "" )); 
    }
}
```

You can also just use `File.WriteAllText` or similar methods to avoid creating the file this way.  Using the `using` block guarantees the file will be closed, even if `Some_Method` raises an exception.

Comment: I can see a lot of usefull advice here, I'll try it out, I think this will do :)

Comment: A question though, what will happen if my file already exists and I try to make another one with same name?

EDIT: I found out, it would just rewrite it, luckily I've managed to fuse my old code with yours and found something that works for me, thanks all :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `File` class as it wraps up a lot of the work for you

Example:

```
private void Create_File(string Create_Directory, string Create_Name)
{
    string pathString = Create_Directory;
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString)) { System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString); }

    pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathString, Create_Name + ".txt");
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, Some_Method(MP.Mwidth, MP.Mheight, MP.Mtype, ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\niit\\deep.docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string str = sr.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Comment: above program for read and open the file which are already created inside the  computer .